# Notification bar overlaying over action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have added `ActionBar` to my android app. It is working fine in `Lollipop`, but in `KitKat` notification bar is overlaying over action bar.
[image].

Code for the layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- The main content view -->

<!-- Your normal content view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/base_activity_toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.squad.run.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:tag="SIDE_MENU"
    tools:layout="@layout/sidemenu_left" />
```

Code for the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/base_activity_toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

From what I have read setting the `fitSystemWindows` attribute to `True` in root layout should solve the problem. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You could use ScrimInsetsFrameLayout as you can see here. https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main_topdrawer.xml

Comment: @PedroOliveira: The library is deprecated.

Comment: Don't worry about that. That library is mine :). I'm not telling you to use the library. I'm just telling you use that layout the same way as I used it too